# Using angular2 in a Spring webapp WITHOUT node.js

Tags: spring, maven, angular

I just made the move from Angular 1 to 2, and now I am going to create a spring mvc maven webapp with angular2 for the front-end side of it.

But everywhere on the internet I see people using node.js for the necessary libraries & plugins. Is there a way I can just use maven dependencies for this?

**App structure:**

```
_ main
   _ java
   _ resources
   _ webapp
       _ components
            _ app.component.ts
       _ img
       _ WEB-INF
       _ index.html
       _ main.ts
```

**main.ts**

```
//getting an error on the bootstrap import 
//because the angular2 folders aren't there because there is no node
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'

import {AppComponent} from './components/app.component.ts'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17104456/755183

Comment: If you want to manage front-end dependencies with Maven, you should check [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/) project. Also there are ways how to invoke Node based tools (such as NPM, Bower or [JSPM](http://jspm.io/)) from Maven - check [maven-frontend-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) (this is what I would prefer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personaly use `Angular2` with a backend in `Java`, the whole packaged in a *.war* file.

Backend libraries are managed with `Maven`, and front end with `NPM`. My project structure is like this :

```
_ backend
  _ src
    _ main
      _ java
      _resources
_ frontend
  <angular-cli project>
  _ package.json ...
```

Note that `NPM` manage all my front dependencies, for now, I don't bundle anything because my application run in debug for now.

I have a deployement script wich copy the bundled version of my frontend in resources/static (or webapp) folder of the backend.

If you want some help to manage your webapp folder for `Angular2`, you can try [AngularCLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). The project is at a very early stage, but you can do some interesting thing with it, and it will help you to create the boilerplate, it will download for you all the dependencies.

Comment: thx, gonna use npm then, thought there would be another way :) but it's fine

Comment: Maybe there is another way, but I don't know him. If your project is quite simple, AngularCLI, is a very good tool. For now there is still some bug when you have a complex project.

Comment: @AdrienBARRAL Hi Adrien, I'm in a similar situation (spring, Angular2 to .war) and I was wondering if there's a way to automatically detect changes and reload them in the browser? Do you have a sample project by any chance? Thanks

Comment: Hi, @Androidicus. When I am in a developping phase I use live-server, or the HTTP server embedded in Angular-cli. In a developping phase, this is not my backend which serve my application.