# Error running npm with Maven

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, maven

I've added the plugins from this post:
[How to deploy a node.js app with maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103748/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-with-maven)
in my pom.xml. 
 When I run a maven build I'm getting this error in the bpm-debug.log:

```
verbose stack Error: spawn git ENOENT

verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)

1434 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)

1434 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)

1434 verbose stack     at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)

1434 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)

1409 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601

1410 error argv "C:\\PROGRA~1\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\PROGRA~1\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
```

Looking at C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

it looks like all the packages have been downloaded. But the error is not specific as to why it is trying to do next. This is the maven command that is being executed.

```
<execution>
<id>exec-npm-install</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<configuration>
<workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/sr/main/resources</workingDirectory>
<executable>npm</executable>
<arguments>
<argument>install</argument>
</arguments>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>exec</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
```

The error in the Eclipse console that I missed initially is this:

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI.git C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-designmodo-Flat-UI-git-ffc5ed04:
```

Which corresponds to this line in package.json:

```
"flat-ui": "git+https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI.git#2.3.0",
```

It appears there was a security certificate issue. I ran this command in bash, and then ran mvn. And it got me past that error:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Feel free to close this question. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure have `git` installed?

Comment: What maven goal are you running? Provide exact command.

Comment: The error on the Eclipse console that I missed initially is being thrown at this execution:

Comment: It appears there was a security certificate issue. I ran this command in bash, and then ran mvn. And it got me past that error:  npm config set strict-ssl false    Feel free to close this question. Thanks.