# Compile typescript to javascript using Maven

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, maven, tomcat

I have a backend application which is running on Tomcat. Currently the project is build using Maven.

I am planning to use typescript in the project. Can we compile Typescript to javascript using Maven. Is there any trusted plugins are available to be used with Maven?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103748/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-with-maven

Comment: It seems to me that this is actually a different question, since the referenced question is purely about node/js deployment. No mention of typescript compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I use Java and Typescript in a combined project too, but I can only recommend to use for every eco-system their own build and dependency project.

Node/Angular/Typescript and Java have different life cycle phases and a completely different dependency management. Because both have their own problems I would avoid to mix them with Maven.

What I am doing is to combine both build systems over a CI. This triggers both builds and take care that all different artifacts are built to the same time.

Comment: Is it like having a front end build separately and host it in webserver and backend build running a tomcat application server?

Comment: Yes, but in the mentioned projects are full Java back-ends and Typescript client-libraries for the front-end provided. The libraries have match with the servers. Finally the TS client libraries a included into complete separated GUI projects.